# How can I stop materials from clipping?

Tags: modeling, materials, uv, image, transparency

I want to model a paper character in 3D. I started by importing the material of the character I want to create using an add-on called "Import images as planes". Then, I arranged the material the way I want it to be, however, when I take a look at the model again it ended up like the image below.
[image: (Left: The back side of the plane, Right: The front side of the plane)]

The material on the back seems about fine, however, the material on the front seems to be overlapped by the material on the back. How can I stop this from happening, and if possible, how can I prevent this in the future?

Comment: Please share your blend file.  I think you're saying that you have two images on two separate planes and you only want to view one from the back and the other from the front but I'm not sure?  Is that your question?

Comment: I'm trying to make a 2D character in a 3D space, I only added one plane, extruded it, kept one face on the front the same and relocate the material on the back to the back sprite. I made the sprite to contain both front sprite and back sprite, I used the "Import Images as Planes" add-on to add transparency to the character, I wanted the front and the back of the plane. to have different sprites respectively And here are the link to the .blend file and the sprite: http://www.filedropper.com/model (.blend) http://www.filedropper.com/acesprt (sprite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should prepare two images A and B such that A flipped horizontally has the same contour (the same alpha channel) as B. Otherwise, you will see that the character changes pose when flipping.

If you do that, then your problem will probably be solved: if you have a a very thin (`0.001 m`) cube with one big face depicting the front of an astronaut, and the other big face depicting the back of the astronaut, you won't be able to see the wrong side, as the right side will cover the other completely (because the alpha channels match).

Without doing the above, you can enable *Backface culling* to not display insides of an object:

[image]

Also, you don't need a cube and a single plane is enough - just use the **Geometry > Backfacing** to determine which side you're displaying:

[image]

Of course for a single plane, the *Backface Culling* has to be disabled.

[image]